# UICollectionView cells are misaligned

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

The screenshot shows a section of a `UICollectionView`. The collection view's width is `294.0`, and its minimum inter-item spacing is 0. The widths of the cells on each row are `117.0, 58.0, 58.0,` and `58.0`. Those widths were calculated dynamically by a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, which, I believe, is necessary since not all cells have the same width. The vertical black lines are the collection view's background. For some reason, the cells in the last row don't line up with the cells on other rows. What might cause this, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: The code is here: https://gist.github.com/csimmons0/ef7933730905d57fb347d803df2d77dd

[image: Misaligned]

Comment: I've found one workaround: adding a dummy cell with a height equal to one pixel and width equal to the collection view's width. The real cells became aligned once I did that. A cleaner solution would be nice though.

Comment: Do you want the space between the cells? If so, why is `minimumInteritemSpacing` not equal to 1?

Comment: @beyowulf Setting minimumInteritemSpacing to a nonzero value doesn't fix the problem. The collection view still bunches any leftover space at the very end in the last row, as opposed to the other rows, where it seems to spread out leftover space.

Comment: Post your code. All of it, if necessary. No one can help with what you've provided.

My point was more, if you want a one point space between cells, why would set `minimumInteritemSpacing == 0` because at minimum you want 1 point between items.

Comment: @beyowulf I added a link to a gist with the code. Ideally there wouldn't be any inter-item spacing, but I couldn't find a way to make that work. When I tried to make the cells' total width equal to the width of the collection view, the layout was as expected on some phones, but on other phones the four cells didn't fit in one row. I assumed that this was due to floating point imprecision issues, which is why I started rounding cells' widths toward zero. As long as four cells fit in a row and the columns are aligned, I don't care how much space is between them.

Comment: @ChristopherSimmons surprisingly I was able to reproduce your issue when I try to create my own collection view that is similar to your collection view. But the issue went away when I set minimumInteritemSpacing to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening if you set a value to minimumInteritemSpacing and your cell size doesn't really reflect the minimumInteritemSpacing. i.e) if your cell sizes create the item spacing 1 and if you set minimumInteritemSpacing to 0, it causes the problem you have. Hopefully somebody can explain this but this is what I found out after I played with my own collection view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minItemSpacing
        }

        collectionView.register(DemoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DemoCell")

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfRows * numberOfColumns
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DemoCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item % 4 == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: firstColumnWidth, height: view.frame.size.height / CGFloat(numberOfRows))
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: regularColumnWidth, height: view.frame.size.height / CGFloat(numberOfRows))
        }
    }

    var minItemSpacing: CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    var numberOfColumns: Int {
        return 4
    }

    var numberOfRows: Int {
        return 8
    }

    var firstColumnWidth: CGFloat {
        return 117
    }

    var regularColumnWidth: CGFloat {
        return (collectionView.frame.size.width - firstColumnWidth - CGFloat(numberOfColumns - 1) * minItemSpacing) / CGFloat(numberOfColumns - 1)
    }
}

class DemoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly. if change layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0, cells in the the last row are all aligned to the left. I created variables so you can play with it. Hope this helps you.